# how to avoid lock or release metadata lock in sqlalchemy using mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy 2.0 with a MySQL database.  If I create some table definitions in my `Metadata()` object (`meta`) using `meta.create_all()` and then immediately drop them using `meta.drop_all()` there is no problem --  tables are correctly created and dropped without a problem.

However, if I read from those tables, after create and before drop, the `drop_all()` fails. I presume this is due to a metadata lock, but I'm not sure how to release the lock i.e. via commit() or close(), i.e. methods of Session objects

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, create_engine, inspect, select
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine(con_str)

meta = MetaData(schema='test')
table1 = Table('table1',meta, Column('id1', Integer, primary_key = True), Column('col1', String(50)))
table2 = Table('table2',meta, Column('id2', Integer, primary_key = True), Column('col2', String(50)))

meta.create_all(bind=engine)
print(f"Tables after creation: {inspect(engine.connect()).get_table_names()}")

# pd.read_sql_query(sql=select(table1), con=engine.connect())

meta.drop_all(bind=engine)
print(f"Tables after drop_all: {inspect(engine.connect()).get_table_names()}")
```

Output:

```
Tables after creation: ['table1', 'table2']
Tables after drop_all: []
```

If I uncomment the `pd.read_sql_query()` line, it will correctly return a `pd.DataFrame` of shape `(0,2)`, but the next line (i.e. the `drop_all()` call) will freeze.

**Question: what is the correct way to unlock the metadata lock or table lock that appears to be placed when query the tables?**

#### Update:

Below is the line from `show processlist;` that indicates the freeze

```
| 432 | <user>        | <host>       | test   | Query   |       3 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP TABLE test.table1 |
```

Comment: Can you `show processlist` /`show engine innodb status` on the server during the `drop_all()` freeze? Which MySQL vesrion?

Comment: thanks @danblack, I'm using MySQL 8.0. I've added the line in process list to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I may have solved this. If I instead persist the connection object, rather than pass `engine.connect()` to the `con` parameter of `pd.read_sql_query()`, and explictly commit, the problem is resolved:

i.e.

```
connection = engine.connect()
pd.read_sql_query(sql=select(table1), con=connection)
connection.commit()
```

When using this approach between `meta.create_all()` and `meta.drop_all()`, the problem is resolved.